# How to allow cross-domain requests in Safari?

Tags: ajax, web-applications, safari, xmlhttprequest

I have webapp I run from localhost (because of debugging) and it makes cross-domain AJAX requests. I can easily set flag for Chrome "--disable-web-security" and the webapp works as expected in Chrome. But I need to do this for Safari on Windows as well. Is there some similar flag or can I set this in Preferences somewhere ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Best I could find http://www.cypressnorth.com/blog/programming/cross-domain-ajax-request-with-json-response-for-iefirefoxchrome-safari-jquery/

Comment: Yes, setting header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); solves this problem. Brain2000 please post it as your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is to set a header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` on the server.

In PHP it's easy like this:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Credit for the answer goes to Brain2000, thanks for suggesting a link in your comment.