# Allowing cross-domain requests in Safari and Chrome? Server response vs. command line arguments

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, safari, cross-domain

I am trying to make cross-domain requests with Safari on Windows. My Safari version is 5.1.2.

This is a classical question. I read in many places that Chrome and Safari allows cross domain requests as long as Server responds with the followin header in the response

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

I have read this post.
[How to allow cross-domain requests in Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826282/how-to-allow-cross-domain-requests-in-safari)
and many others on the stackoverflow site too.

However, none of them answers my question.

I am having problems with Chrome AND Safari doing cross-domain AJAX requests even though I am sending the necessary header back from the server.

I finally ran Chrome with "--disable-web-security". Then it worked.

My questions:

1) What do I do with Safari? Do I use a similar command line argument?

2) More importantly, can I someone please tell me whether cross-domain functionality is allowed in Chrome and Safari by default as long as server responds with the header or do I have to make sure that

a) server responds with a header

AND

b) browser is started with a proper argument.

Comment: There are a lot of details to making cross-domain requests work properly. It all depends on the type of request you are trying to make. Can you give more details about your request? You can learn more about making CORS requests here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem. Reading more about CORS helped [html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors](http://html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors). I realized that my requests were triggering preflight requests (OPTIONS) and the server was not set up to handle these requests properly. The reason it was causing preflight requests was because I was using JQuery and it was adding a custom header into my requests. I modified my code to prevent addition of this extra header and my requests no longer needed preflight requests. Now I do not have to disable web security and it works fine.

Comment: Can you say exactly how you modified your code? What was the extra header?  I may be having this exact same problem.

Comment: Check the cors documentation link above. Check when preflight requests are not needed. Check your http communication via firefug or a similar browser tool and examine all the headers section of your http requests.

Comment: It's apparently not custom (X-*) headers but the Content-Type request header: "If you set this value to anything other than application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain you will trigger a preflight request." Can I just say that this all seems silly - where's the justification for this madness?

Comment: I'm also having the same problem. for development purpose I want to host my API to separate domain. How can I stop this preflight request. I've `application/json` in my Content-Type request header.