# $.ajax breaks in mobile browser

Tags: android, jquery, python, google-chrome

I have created a small `python` app to show the [demo](https://github.com/kracekumar/test-flask).

### HTML

```
<html>
<body>
    <button id="button"> Click for JSON Response </button>
    <div id="update"></div>
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='jquery-1.8.3.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#button").on('click', function(e){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8888/json",
            success: function(msg){
                $("#update").html(msg['msg']);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Clicking on the button yields `msg` from [server](https://github.com/kracekumar/test-flask/blob/master/app.py#L12). But on mobile, following error is raised.

```
POST http://localhost:8888/json  jquery-1.8.3.js:8434
send jquery-1.8.3.js:8434
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery-1.8.3.js:7986
(anonymous function) 192.168.0.101:8
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.8.3.js:3058
elemData.handle.eventHandle
```

`$.ajax` submits fails in chrome android mobile browser in android 4.2.2.

### Edit

1.`adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:chrome_devtools_remote`
Then accessed via ip address of the machine with portno(8888) and console log was captured by visiting `http://localhost:9222` in laptop.
2. After adding console.log(err) in $.ajax, error message in console is

```
Object {readyState: 0, setRequestHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function,      getResponseHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
abort: function ( statusText ) {
always: function () {
complete: function () {
done: function () {
error: function () {
fail: function () {
getAllResponseHeaders: function () {
getResponseHeader: function ( key ) {
overrideMimeType: function ( type ) {
pipe: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
progress: function () {
promise: function ( obj ) {
readyState: 0
responseText: ""
setRequestHeader: function ( name, value ) {
state: function () {
status: 0
statusCode: function ( map ) {
statusText: "error"
success: function () {
then: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Is your mobile device running a web server at port 8888?

Comment: @mori57: Updated more info.

Comment: What do you get if you add console.log(msg); before your $("#update") line? Can you see if you're getting anything back? If not, have you tried adding a error: to the call, to see what is coming back from the server? Neat trick, btw, all that. (Sorry, I was thinking of the jqXHR object's fail event callback.)

Comment: The `post` isn't submitted, that is the issue.

Comment: Well, if you're getting something back from the err object (statusText: "error"), then the request is being sent. I'm not certain, but you might also need to use something to okay the request to your server to accept cross-domain requests. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641442/phonegap-jquery-ajax-cross-domain-requests-work-in-browser-fail-in-android-sdk

Comment: And sorry, haven't found a sample for Python (and don't know Python), but I would assume there's a way to do something like this in that language as well. Here's another SO-answer that links to CORS documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679736/allowing-cross-domain-requests-in-safari-and-chrome-server-response-vs-command

Answer (score 0):

If you are tunneling your request data through you need to go to Chrome Canary, go to chrome://experiments then "Enable Dev Tools experiements"

[image: Enable Devtools Experiments]

then in dev tools go to the settings

[image: Settings]

Go to Experiments and enable port forwarding.

[image]

Refresh.

Then go to chrome://inspect (with your device plugged in) and go to devtools for the page.

And then select "Port Forwarding"

[image: port forwarding]

And add the maps of "device ports" to your testing server ip address and port.